# Daemonizing a rake task in ruby. Best solution?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, process, rake-task, daemons

I have a rake task that polls an Amazon SQS queue indefinitely, which needs to be kept alive on a server. What would be the best solution for doing this? Any decent, maintained gems for daemonizing, that would be a good solution to this problem?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers :)

Comment: How did you fit it? I have exactly the same requirement.

Answer (score 1):

There are gems for this, yes. You can checkout https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/daemonizing for a list of the gems along with the popularity / issues on each.

But since Ruby 1.9.3, there's ["Process.daemon"](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Process.html#method-c-daemon) which does exactly what you need. You can checkout the link here for details - http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Process.html#method-c-daemon

Here's a sample gist with how to create a pid - https://gist.github.com/sbusso/1978385

The above gist helped me a great deal.